# Rename multiple files in Linux following pattern

Tags: linux, rename, file-rename

I have a directory with some files that are messed up:

```
1243435.pdf
1222424.pdf
643234234.pdf
3423436pdf
45435435pdf
343432.pdf.meta
345232.pdf.meta
3434311pdf.meta
12121234pdf.meta
```

Files with extension .pdf or .pdf.meta are OK and should stay the same, but how can I rename only the ones that don't have . in front of pdf?

```
45435435pdf > 45435435.pdf
12121234pdf.meta > 12121234.pdf.meta
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find a better method.

```
find . -type f -regex '\.\/[^.]+pdf\.?[meta]*?' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\pdf/\.pdf}"' -- {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match all the files with `*[^.]pdf`, i.e. anything followed by a non-dot followed by `pdf`. To extract the prefix, use parameter expansion:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
for file in *[^.]pdf ; do
    prefix=${file%pdf}
    mv "$file" "$prefix".pdf
done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First

Save your files in a list e.g. `list.txt`

#### Second

Try a dry-run to see it will be correct

```bash
perl -lne 's/(?<=\d)(?=pdf)/./g && print' list.txt
```

Which for your input, has this output

```bash
3423436.pdf
45435435.pdf
3434311.pdf.meta
12121234.pdf.meta
```

#### Thrid

Run it

```bash
perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/(?<=\d)(?=pdf)/./g && rename($old,$_)' list.txt
```

If you have lots of files, this is the fastest way.